# In Gtk, how do I make a CellRendererToggle in a TreeViewColumn with multiple CellRenderers only get toggled when the checkbox itself is clicked?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

I have a `TreeModel` representing a tree of `Tag`s. Each `Tag` has these
properties, among others:

```
string Name
bool Active
Tag Parent
TagList Children //basically just a List<Tag>
```

The `TreeView` has a single column, with two `CellRenderer`s: a
`CellRendererToggle` for `Active`, and a `CellRendererText` for `Name`. I want
them in the same column, because multiple columns gets messy as you
get farther down the descendants in the `TreeView`.

My problem is that when I click *anywhere* in the column, the
`CellRendererToggle` is toggled. This is problematic, because I want to
do things like dragging the tags, and renaming them inline. Is there
any way to make the `CellRendererToggle` *only* get toggled when I click
on the checkbox itself, without moving it to a separate column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `CellRenderer`'s `Mode` to `Activatable`:

```
renderer.Mode = CellRendererMode.Activatable;
```

If a renderer is not activatable, but another renderer in the column is, Gtk passes on the click to that renderer. Setting your non-toggle renderers to be activatable, too, keeps them from passing on the click.